# I can't seem to access certain features from the terminal

Tags: python, windows, terminal, directory

First of all, I am not a tech genius so definitely let me know if I am saying something stupid. The problem I've been having is that when I try to run specific commands for Python or GoLang I have to choose its specific directory first:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\(Redacted)>python --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\(Redacted)>cd C:\Users\Uday_Randhawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

C:\Users\(Redacted)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39>python --version
Python 3.9.0
```

I don't know what's causing this but would love any help, even where to post this on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need to add your python installation to path.

Comment: see this [guide](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/) for step-by-step procedure.